# Set runtime layout paramters in layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I know how to set absolute layout parameters for a View in layout xml files for a View. Such as

```
android:layout_width="30dp", 
android_layout_height="match_parent"
```

But is it possible to set these kind of parameters in xml layout files:

(1) Make a TextView width equals 80% of the screen width and TextView height equals half of the TextView width.

(2) Make an ImageView dimensions the same as the Bitmap it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not with standard layouts. That would have to be done at runtime; or you could create a custom layout and attributes, and do your own measuring and layout.
2. Yup, just set the width and height to `wrap_content`.